# Yarn error on teamcity build: "Unknown: unknown error, open"

Tags: teamcity, hadoop-yarn

The first step in the TC build process is to run "yarn install" in the directory: `D:\TeamCity\Agent\work\MyApp`

this is successfull up until: `[4/4] Rebuilding all packages...`

at which point this error is thrown:

````
```[Step 1/5] error An unexpected error occurred: "D:\\TeamCity\\Agent\\work\\MyApp\\node_modules\\@babel\\runtime-corejs2\\node_modules\\core-js: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'D:\\TeamCity\\Agent\\temp\\buildTmp\\yarn--1592234614361-0.5350564069819825\\yarn'"```
````

From what I can tell here, its trying to open the temp folder, but cant? or cant find it?

This does not happen consistently. It seems to be random, or whenever there is an extended time between builds. We cannot determine a common pattern. To fix it, we just re-run the build.

We have tried 'yarn install --verbose' and 'yarn install --force' the former showed nothing usefull on output, and --force was a guess at best.

I'm hoping someone can give a bit more context as to exactly what that error might mean.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfkkE.png)